# Aggregate collections MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

I am wondering if there's a way to aggregate collections in folders or in father collections.

conceptually:

`collections_father: 
{collection1 : list of documents,
collection2 : list of documents,
collection3 : list of documents}`

if possible, how to do it and how to query document inside a collection?

Thank you

Comment: It's not possible, at the mongodb level anyway. As with RDBMSs, a collection is a basic storage unit meant to hold documents (each having a distinct _id). You can't just nest them together.

Comment: (Why would you want to parent collections)? If you find yourself needing to do that, you might consider just storing more than one type of document in a single collection.

Comment: @WiredPrairie For example for each published post i need to create a collection in which i store all likes on this post, i can't do it with a single document cause max-size is 16MB, so i need to create a collection, but i think it'd be heavy having thousands and thousand of collections in a single database. how can i do it?

Comment: A collection can store any documents you'd like. Each document can be up to 16MB in size, but collections have no such restriction.